# Virtualbox with WXP, static public IP on Ubuntu Server host

Tags: virtualbox, ip, ubuntu-server

I have a Ubuntu server machine with 2 networks cards, one with a static public IP, connected to the router and the other for creating a NAT with other computers on the LAN.

On this machine I installed a VirtualBox guest with WXP with a new public IP address.

The problem is that even if the WXP reaches the internet without problem using the public IP address, from internet you cannot see the machine nor ping it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is likely related to the WXP virtual machine configuration. The VM Internface is probably configured as [NAT](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_nat).

In order to provide it with an externally visible IP you need to configure it to [Bridged mode](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#idp11916480).

Have in mind as well that if your public IP is provided by your Internet provider you may have issues assigning a public IP to the VM as most providers provide you with just one IPv4 address. If that is the case you can use [NAT + PAT](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#natforward)

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the VM is configured in Bridged mode: VBoxManage modifyvm "WXP" --nic1 bridged --bridgeadapter1 eth0.I do really think that is a Linux server related problem, because i have another server, but with window OS, with an WXP guest machine and public IP address and all works fine

Comment: Alan, have you rebooted after the modifyvm command?

I use bridged VMs (windows and linux guests using DHCP) on Linux host without issues.

Comment: Yes i rebooted, i also rebooted the server... but the wxp machine IP is not seen from the internet :(

Comment: have you tried configuring static IPs on guest WXP VM?

Comment: it is configured with a static public ip

Comment: Can you run tcpdump from the Host on the bridge interface and:

* Connect to an externat host from the WXP guest
* perform a ping to WXP guest?

Make sure you include the ARP entries. 

By the way, I assume you have disabled firewalls on both the Guest and Host?

Comment: I feel so stupid... I was sure it was a firewall disabled XP machine and didn't checked. Thank you for remember me this (even if my first thought has been, "sure I have no firewall..."). Sorry for having wasted your time and thanks again

Comment: :-) No time wasted but a +1 helps to cover the debt! :P